# There's a way to trace or log network with visual studio (or other app)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, networking, network-traffic

I had some classes that make web request and I can't see the endpoint because its encapsulated in a dll.

so.. there's a way to trace/log this request (http, https) with their parameters?

I tried fiddler, changed the proxy of machine.config, but nothing works...

The scenario is: 
Local IIS website that make http request to and remote URL encapsulated in DLL and i can't see or configure the endpoint.